# How to do this Scroll hide fab button in Jetpack Compose with transaction

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How to do this Scroll hide fab button in Jetpack Compose with transaction

Like this I need it:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to listen to the scroll state and apply `AnimatedVisibiltiy`. Here is an example using `LazyColumn` with `LazyListState` (you could also use `Column` with `ScrollState`)

```
@Composable
fun Screen() {

    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    val fabVisibility by derivedStateOf {
        listState.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0
    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        LazyColumn(
            Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            state = listState,
        ) {
            items(count = 100, key = { it.toString() }) {
                Text(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    text = "Hello $it!")
            }
        }

        AddPaymentFab(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                .padding(bottom = 40.dp),
            isVisibleBecauseOfScrolling = fabVisibility
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun AddPaymentFab(
    modifier: Modifier,
    isVisibleBecauseOfScrolling: Boolean,
) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    AnimatedVisibility(
        modifier = modifier,
        visible = isVisibleBecauseOfScrolling,
        enter = slideInVertically {
            with(density) { 40.dp.roundToPx() }
        } + fadeIn(),
        exit = fadeOut(
            animationSpec = keyframes {
                this.durationMillis = 120
            }
        )
    ) {
        ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
            text = { Text(text = "Add Payment") },
            onClick = { },
            icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "Add Payment") }
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can use `NestedScrollConnection` and `AnimatedVisibility` to change visibilty of `ExtendedFloatingActionButton`.

1. You should use `remeberSaveable` to store state of `ExtendedFloatingActionButton`:

```
// Visibility for FAB, could be saved in viewModel
val isVisible = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }
```

2. Implement `NestedScrollConnection`, you can use your values to show/hide FAB:

```
// Nested scroll for control FAB
val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
    object : NestedScrollConnection {
        override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
            // Hide FAB
            if (available.y < -1) {
                isVisible.value = false
            }

            // Show FAB
            if (available.y > 1) {
                isVisible.value = true
            }

            return Offset.Zero
        }
    }
}
```

3. Implement `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` inside `AnimatedVisibility`, set visible value from `isVisible` and set enter and exit animation, in my case I use `slideInVertically` for enter animation and `slideOutVertically` for exit animation:

```
AnimatedVisibility(
    visible = isVisible.value,
    enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { it * 2 }),
    exit = slideOutVertically(targetOffsetY = { it * 2 }),
) {
    ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
        onClick = {
            // FAB click
        }
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Extended FAB"
        )
    }
}
```

4. Apply `NestedScrollConnection` to scrollable content, in my case to `LazyColumn`:

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(innerPadding)
        .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection),
) {
    items(100) { index ->
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
            text = "Item: $index"
        )
    }
}
```

Full code of MainActivity:

```
package com.andreirozov.animatedfab

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.animation.slideInHorizontally
import androidx.compose.animation.slideInVertically
import androidx.compose.animation.slideOutHorizontally
import androidx.compose.animation.slideOutVertically
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.rounded.Add
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
import androidx.compose.material3.FabPosition
import androidx.compose.material3.FloatingActionButton
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollConnection
import androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.NestedScrollSource
import androidx.compose.ui.input.nestedscroll.nestedScroll
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.andreirozov.animatedfab.ui.theme.AnimatedFabTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AnimatedFabApp()
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AnimatedFabApp() {
    AnimatedFabTheme {
        // Visibility for FAB, could be saved in viewModel
        val isVisible = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }

        // Nested scroll for control FAB
        val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
            object : NestedScrollConnection {
                override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                    // Hide FAB
                    if (available.y < -1) {
                        isVisible.value = false
                    }

                    // Show FAB
                    if (available.y > 1) {
                        isVisible.value = true
                    }

                    return Offset.Zero
                }
            }
        }

        Scaffold(
            floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,
            floatingActionButton = {
                AnimatedVisibility(
                    visible = isVisible.value,
                    enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { it * 2 }),
                    exit = slideOutVertically(targetOffsetY = { it * 2 }),
                ) {
                    ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
                        onClick = {
                            // FAB click
                        }
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Extended FAB"
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        ) { innerPadding ->
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(innerPadding)
                    .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection),
            ) {
                items(100) { index ->
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                        text = "Item: $index"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It may be late, but after struggling with this issue for a while, I was able to find the right solution from the Animation Codelab sourcecode.

The difference between this and the previous answer is that in this way, as soon as the page is scrolled up, the Fab is displayed and there is no need to reach the first item of the page to display the Fab.

step one: getting an instance of the lazyListState class inside LazyColumn

```
val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
```

Step two: Creating a top level variable to hold the scroll state so that recompositions do not change the state value unintentionally.

```
var isScrollingUp by mutableStateOf(false)
```

Step three: just copy this composable Extension Function inside the file

```
@Composable
private fun LazyListState.isScrollingUp(): Boolean {
    var previousIndex by remember(this) { mutableStateOf(firstVisibleItemIndex) }
    var previousScrollOffset by remember(this) { mutableStateOf(firstVisibleItemScrollOffset) }
    return remember(this) {
        derivedStateOf {
            if (previousIndex != firstVisibleItemIndex) {
                previousIndex > firstVisibleItemIndex
            } else {
                previousScrollOffset >= firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
            }.also {
                previousIndex = firstVisibleItemIndex
                previousScrollOffset = firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
            }
        }
    }.value
}
```

Step four: Open an AnimatedVisibility block and pass the isScrollingUp variable as its first parameter. And finally, making the Fab and placing it inside the AnimatedVisibility

```
AnimatedVisibility(visible = isScrollingUp) {

 FloatingActionButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
        // your code
    }

}
```

have fun!

Comment: when i scroll down and fab button is hidden and go to other screen then come back to the current screen, the isScrollingUp change to default value and fab button shown. please fix it.

Comment: I Find the problem, you must set default  value of previousIndex , previousScrollOffset by zero.